# Django DateTime field received a naive datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I've seen this question asked a few times and I have followed the answers suggested, however im still getting the error:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1430: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField CircuitMaintenance.end_time received a naive datetime (2017-02-24 23:59:59) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

From what ive read using django utils timezone instead of datetime.now() should of solved the issue, but it has not. I have also got the following settings in my settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

code

```
from django.utils import timezone
dt_now = timezone.now()
days_away = datetime(dt_now.year, dt_now.month, dt_now.day) + timedelta(days)
days_away_end = days_away + timedelta(hours=23,minutes=59,seconds=59)
maintenance = CircuitMaintenance.objects.filter(start_time__gte=days_away, end_time__lte=days_away_end,circuit__site_data__site_type="Major Site")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the timezone info is lost when creating `days_away`. You can simply add `timezone.now()` to a `timedelta`:

```
days_away = timezone.now() + timedelta(days)
```

To default time data to midnight, you can use `replace`:

```
days_away = timezone.now().replace(hour=0,minute=0, second=0) + timedelta(days)
```

Also, note that what you have is a warning, not an error.

Comment: that works but days_away time needs to start at midnight and not now, how do i get that working?